# Assign next available person when resources are depleted

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I'm creating a resources spreadsheet in Google Sheets for my community to post their haves/needs in response to the coronavirus. I'd like to automatically assign a person who has an item to a person who needs that item, but only if that person hasn't already been assigned to others.

In other words, if person A and person B both have one roll of toilet paper each, and person C needs 1, person D needs 1, and person E needs 1, I would like person C to be matched with A, D with B, and person E to show "IN NEED" (of someone to donate). Example:

[image: example A]

Or, as another example, say that person A has 3 rolls of TP and person B has 1. Person C asks for 2 and person D asks for 1, so both C and D should both be assigned person A but the next person who asks should be assigned to person B.

Obviously those numbers work out nicely, but it would get complicated if say person A and B each had 1 roll1 of TP and person C asked for 2 (then would need to show both people as assigned to person C).

This is my formula as of now (very basic): `=if(ISTEXT(I4),IFERROR(index($C$4:$E$1000,match(I4,$D$4:$D$1000,0),1),"IN NEED"),"")`

Thank you for any help you can offer!!

[Link to sheet for more detailed example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dsDN_Fm-wk5VdbxpzLgbA8MIBb6OVRzj5V-h200bN_0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Still need help on this one ? I've made an Excel worksheet with your sample data.https://framapic.org/H0hfc2e0qaBE/rva6MiZwUlPj.PNG I don't try it yet with Google-Sheets.

Comment: @E.Wiest are you serious?? I would kiss you if it weren't for the covid!! that looks perfect!

Comment: OK. Let me some time to finish it properly and i send it to you.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much @E.Wiest!

Comment: Hey @E.Wiest, any luck on this? I'd take it at any stage you have it, doesn't have to be perfect! Thanks again!!

Comment: Hi ! I'm sorry for the lack of news. Work is almost done. The worksheet is massive and the debugging process consumes a lot of time. I'm testing it with some random data and i'm adding a new feature. https://framapic.org/lEAQU8U8EpUk/PCiHBk52rSRQ.gif It will be out tomorrow (that's not an april fool). Compatibility with GoogleSheets will be OK since I used generic formulas. I keep you in touch.

Comment: that looks fantastic!! thank you so much.

Comment: And i'm late ! It took a lot of time. Post is just below with some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. So here's the sheet which still needs plenty of improvements, corrections.

[Excel sheet](https://seafile.unistra.fr/d/03c644af7d8e4952bf9e/)

The file is massive with some very long formulas and multiple tables to compute intermediate data. The sheet supports up to 100 different items (toilet paper, water, beans, etc.) and 1000 requests (need) and 1000 offers (have).

Features added :

- conditional formatting on the "offers" cells (if something is missing, cells are borded with a red line)
- number of items to ask to the assigned person has been added (number between '()')

TODO :

- stress test the sheet, pretty sure some specific cases causing errors still exist
- comment the file to understand the mechanism of the sheet
- hide the mechanism of the sheet ("column helpers")
- test on googlesheet (should work, generic formulas were used)
- optimize formulas to get a faster" sheet

I'll update it as fast as I can. Questions/Comments are welcomed.

Comment: wow, that is next level excel right there! unbelievable, thank you so much. You went so above and beyond here, really great job!!